# ensure block of code runs when program exits

Tags: ruby

I want to make sure that a peice of code runs when the ruby program ends. I used the following ways but they do not work in some situations.

```
def a_method
   # do some work
ensure
   # code that must be run when method ends and if program exits when it still in this method.
end

def a_method
   at_exit{ 
      # run code that needs to be run when process exists
   }
   # do some work
ensure
   # do code that needs to be run when method ends
end
```

those two methods works very well when the process is killed with a signal other than `kill -9` 'although I didn't tried all the signals'. 
So is there a way to make sure that code runs even if the process is killed with this signal?

Comment: @ndn at_exit does not do the job when the process is killed with `kill -9`, it works only when the process is terminated, not killed.

Comment: because `kill -9` does not exit the program, it kills it :)

Comment: @NafaaBoutefer, if you can handle `kill -9` in the process being killed there is something wrong with your OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signal 9 is non-catchable, non-ignorable kill, by design. Your `at_exit` will not run because the operating system will simply terminate any process that receives this signal, not giving it any chance to do any extra work.